# Snowflake - Is there any way to concatenate a SQL query using UDF defined in JavaScript to a where clause inside another UDF defined in SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a UDF2 in JavaScript language which returns set of query statements as a String based on the input we pass. Here , this String value should be appended to the where clause as SQL Text in UDF1 defined in SQL language.

*for example :
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND
(
DB.SCHEMA.UDF2(PARM_1)  -- *This UDF2 returns a query set in String type. Now its checking as a Boolean condition in UDF1 but I want it to be concatenated as a SQL query to the existing where clause*
)*

Please suggest me any approach to achieve this in Snowflake.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code example of what you've already tried?

Comment: Two small sample before and after tables would help understand the requirement too.

Comment: I created an UDF in JavaScript to return some statements based on the input parameter. When I am calling this UDF in main function which is defined in SQL language , I am getting an error ,Boolean value is not recognized since the return value of 2nd UDF is a String . What I needed here is that returned String should be changed to executable SQL Text and should append to the part above in main function where this UDF is called.

Comment: The return statement of the UDF should act as a filter in where condition in the main function.